# Why do rotated images appear differently in css table?

Tags: html, css

I am experimenting with creating a table using css. The code below compares two tables, one created using conventional html table tags and one using css. Each table displays two images, one rotated and one not.  In the html table the rotated image aligns with the non-rotated image.  However in the css table this does not occur.  I am not sure why this is the case.

```css
  .rotate90 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  DIV.table {
    display: table;
  }
  DIV.tr {
    display: table-row;
  }
  SPAN.td {
    display: table-cell;
  }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <span class="td"><img src="https://placehold.it/400x200&text=one" class="rotate90" alt="Image" border=3 height=200 width=400></img></span>
    <span class="td"><img src="https://placehold.it/200x400&text=two" alt="Image" border=3 height=400 width=200></img></span>
  </div>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://placehold.it/400x200&text=one" class="rotate90" alt="Image" border=3 height=200 width=400></img>
    </td>
    <td><img src="https://placehold.it/200x400&text=two" alt="Image" border=3 height=400 width=200></img>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: attach the HTML code also

Comment: you are missing a `}` in your CSS so no table is created in the first case. You should also correctly use `img` tag and avoid uppercase in the CSS

Comment: Apologies Temani, oversight when copying across content.

Answer (score 1):

in your code the div img is not in  center of div

and in table the vertical alignment of image is center

the center are different for both images that's why is not rotating properly

check the image [image: before rotating]

Comment: Hi Salunke,  Thanks, following your advice I have added the alignment modifications to the css and also translated the image after rotation to align with the top left of the table cell